# custom-sql when I only imported the service (Liferay)

Tags: java, sql, liferay, liferay-service-builder

Hey guys this is a Liferay question,

I am using service builder to communicate to my database. thing is I am using the same tables for two of my portlets, so I imported the jar created in one of my portlets to the other one,,
but then I need to create a custom sql on both of them.. how do I create the finderImpl class? I don't have the persistence folder on my other portlet because the service.jar was only imported..
am I doing it right? what should I do with this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your second project does not contain custom entity then create a dummy entity with help of service builder so that service builder will create service structure i.e Dummy LocalServiceImpl, ServiceImpl for you.

To create dummy entity, don't mention any column in entity element of service.xml

```
<service-builder package-path="com.custom">
    <author>YourName</author>
    <namespace>mycustom</namespace>

    <entity name="MyDummyEntity" local-service="true" remote-service="true" >

    </entity>
<service-builder>
```

So it will create com.custom.service..... packages.

Now create **com.custom.service.persistance** package and then go ahead with the [custom sql concept of liferay](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/06/liferay-custom-sql-on-multiple-tables.html). i.e by creating finder and implementing the same.

Your finder class definition would look like :

> public MyDummyEntityFinderImpl extends
>   BasePersistenceImpl  implements MyDummyEntityFinder{
>
> .... }

Comment: that wasss what I was thinking, although I haven't even tried it because I couldn't really imagine how it could be possible.. I mean how could that even be connected to the table?? if you could explain the concept behind it for me..                                                                                  btw I have done a different approach by doing all the custom-sql on the first portlet and then copy the service jar into the other portlet.. although I have not finished yet so I'm not really sure if this would work..

Comment: It won't create any table in DB as we are not specifying any column, it will give you the structure i.e Impl classes and then you can create your finder by creating xxx.service.persistence package. It will allow you to take the advantage of custom sql.